# Does this sentence make sense?

Tags: creative-writing, poetry, syntactic-analysis

Does this make sense in a creative sense and it is grammatically or structurally correct?

*A heart so pure angel would implore*

What I'm trying to get at is "a heart so pure that it makes angels envious". It makes sense in my head but I might be thinking in another language. Another sentence structure I thought of is

*A heart so pure angels would die for*

or

*Angels would die for a heart so pure*

Comment: In the first one I would say "angels" rather than "angel", and then it would feel okay structurally - not that poetry has to be grammatically correct, but you don't want anything too jarring unless done on purpose. That use of "implore" is a bit confusing though: it sounds poetic, but it's not clear what it is supposed to mean. (I know you explained what you want it to mean, but the line on its own is unclear.)

Comment: A heart so pure angels would adore??  Or  ... an angel would adore??

Comment: @nnnnnn I agree with the plural for Angel. With that single change, the whole first line works and sounds beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

The third one seems like the best one.
Maybe the first could be adjusted to "A heart so pure an angel would implore for it" but that kind of takes down the short-and-sweet aspect. The first one makes enough sense but maybe see if you can rearrange the words to be a bit clearer